# Xpath returns blank page doesn't echo the values

Tags: php

With the code below I get only blank page the name or the nickname is not getting echoed back. I crossed checked the path its correct still its not echoing anything back

```
<?php

$url="http://www.mans-best-friend.org.uk/dog-breeds-alphabetical-list.htm";

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1');
$html = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

$mydoc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(empty($html)) die("EMPTY HTML");

    $mydoc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

    $my_xpath = new DOMXPath($mydoc);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//*[@id="table94"]/tbody/tr/td' );    

    foreach( $nodes as $node )
    {  
    $title=$my_xpath->query( 'p[@data-iceapc="1"]/span/a/font', $node );
    $nickname=$my_xpath->query( 'p[@data-iceapc="2"]/span/a/font', $node );
    echo $title." ".$nickname."<br>";     
    }

?>
```

In case you can't find the p element. Scroll to the part where dog names are. For e.g. **Affenpinscher** right click on it and select inspect - it shows the p element.

Comment: If i look at the source code of your referenced url, there is no `p` element with a `data-iceapc` attribute. Therefore your xpath cannot match.

Comment: its there ...scroll to the part where dog names are tht for .g Affenpinscher right click on it and select inspect ...it shows the p element

Comment: This attribute comes from one of the many trackers that are on this page. Try with some adblock enabled or simply watch the html code you get from curl and you will see that this attribute is not part of the original source.

Comment: ok so based on what u get how do i extract what i want from tht

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to "fix" the html code for the xpath to properly work because it contains too many errors. In this case im extracting only the needed table with id table94.

Afterwards you can use xpath on the dom object to get your desired data:

```
<?php
$url="http://www.mans-best-friend.org.uk/dog-breeds-alphabetical-list.htm";

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1');
$html = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

$html = preg_replace('/^.*(<table[^>]*id="table94">.*?<\/table>).*$/is', '\1', $html);

$mydoc = new DOMDocument();
$mydoc->loadHTML($html);

$my_xpath = new DOMXPath($mydoc);

$nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//tr' );    

foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    if ($my_xpath->query('td[position()=last()-1]/p/span/a/font', $node)->length > 0) {
        echo $my_xpath->query('td[position()=last()-1]/p/span/a/font', $node)->item(0)->textContent.' ';
        echo $my_xpath->query('td[position()=last()]/p/span/font', $node)->item(0)->textContent."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives error Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array  on line 24 .i.e the echo line

Comment: I've edited the answer to use `item` method instead of array access.

Comment: ok i just replaced 'td[position()=last()-1]/p/span/a/font', $node)[0] with 'td[position()=last()-1]/p/span/a/font', $node)->item(0) and it worked

Comment: just for my info what this do td[position()=last()-1

Comment: This select the second last td inside the parent element. This is needed because on the first rows of each letter the first td is only the letter.